# Set SharedPreferences to save Switch Statement Case

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I really confused to save my Switch statement so when the game reopen button that had been VISIBLE is Save, so I do some coding with SharedPreferences like this

```
f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent level1 = new Intent ();
                    level1.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.levelone");
                    startActivityForResult (level1, 0);              
                }             
            });     
        }   

    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1){
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, level1); 

        f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
        f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);
        SharedPreferences resultcode = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = resultCode.edit(); 
        editor.putBoolean("IsFinished", true);
        editor.commit();

    boolean resultcode = preferences.getBoolean("IsFinished", true);


        switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:  f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
```

There is the an error on different line

First in `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = resultCode.edit();`

I got this error *Cannot invoke edit() on the primitive type int*

Second, `boolean resultcode = preferences.getBoolean("IsFinished", true);`

I got two error like this

*preferences cannot be resolved* and *Duplicate local variable*

Can anyone help me to fix the code or giving another solution code to save the Switch Statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### error no:1

There is a typo in your code. Notice the **C** in `resultCode.edit()`

Replace

```
    SharedPreferences resultcode = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = resultCode.edit();
```

with

```
    SharedPreferences resultcode = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = resultcode.edit();
```

Actually, in your code, it is `resultcode` which is the `SharedPreference`, but you was calling `edit()` on `resultCode`

### error:2

I think you are trying to get a boolean value that is stored in the SharedPreference. For that, what you are doing is wrong.

It should be done as follows

```
boolean result = resultcode.getBoolean("IsFinished", true);
```

Actually, it is `resultcode` which refers to your `SharedPreference` in your Java class and not  `preferences`. `preferences` is just a name given to the xml file that is saved in your local device.

Please take a look in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more details about SharedPreferences.

Comment: also, it's a poor name for `SharedPreferences` instance

Comment: @Lal oh okaay i got it, so "preferences" is a name of save data in my local device? or "preference" is name of current xml being used?

Comment: it is the name of the xml file that is saved locally to save data.. @Ricci

Comment: Great.. :) Glad that it helped bro.. :)

Comment: so did i need to used boolean result, or just the 4 lines sharedpreference in my code above to saved the data?

Comment: Sorry..i didnt get you...could you please explain it a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As Lal said, you have a typo. Personally, I prefer one-liner `SharedPreferences` with the key `String` as a `private static String` at the top of the class.

The code below is derived from [one of my projects](https://github.com/JohnPersano/CrimeTalk-Reader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/org/crimetalk/utils/PreferenceUtils.java).

```
private static final String KEY_ISFINISHED = "prefs_isfinished";

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit().putBoolean(KEY_ISFINISHED, myboolean).commit();
```

Using this code, you minimize typos. Aside from code typos, a typo in the key will make sure your preference is never saved/retrieved correctly which is why I 'advocate' for the use of the `static String`. You will also notice from my link that all of my preferences are managed by a single class which means I do not have to repeat code in other classes to retrieve/store a particular preference. Generally speaking, less code == less chance of errors.